# Format DropDownList.TextValue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

My stored procedure is like this

```
SELECT Id, StudentName
FROM xyz
```

I have a drop down list in asp.net, which I am loading as :

```
ddlA.DataSource = // Some source
ddlA.DataTextField = "Id" + " -" + "StudentName";
ddlA.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlA.DataBind();
ddlA.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select one", "0"));
```

But at the `Databind()` statement, I am getting this error:

> System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Id-StudentName'.

In text part of the dropdown list, I want to display the concatenated value of `Id - StudentName`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0} - {1}";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Id,StudentName";
```

It seems that it's not achievable automatically, e.g. see [this MS Connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/103308/multiple-data-bound-properties-for-datatextfield-on-dropdownlist).

---

Thus do that programmatically:

```
foreach (var row in table.Rows)
{
    row.Field<string>("text") = String.Format(..);
}
```

or

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    new ListItem { Text = String.Format(..); }; 
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error at databinding "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Id,StudentName'.

Comment: But it still does not work, the format string considers the ',' as a thousand seperator instead of a property name seperator.

Comment: The link is not working, I solved it now by selecting a new annonymous object that has a Name property displaying the combined text.

Comment: The __first__ solution __doesn't work__, go with third solution.

Comment: @MrFox new annonymous object ?

Comment: @Kiquenet; yeah, the answer is from 2011 when MS Connect still existed, it was retired almost 3 years ago.

Answer (score 16):

You can use LINQ to make a new datasource containing a displayfield which is formatted, the way you want it to be, like:

```
var datasource = from x in products
                 select new {
                     x.Id,
                     x.Code,
                     x.Description,
                     DisplayField = String.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Code, x.Description)
                 };

comboBox.DataSource = datasource;
comboBox.DataValueField = "Id";
comboBox.DataTextField = "DisplayField";
comboBox.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve it by following code

```
dsStudent.Tables[0].Columns.Add("IdWithStudenName",typeof(string),"Id + ' - ' + StudenName");
DropDownList1.DataSource = dsStudent;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "IdWithStudenName";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));
```

For more understanding refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810291.aspx).

Comment: I have List<Entity> not DataTable or DataSet.

Answer (score 3):

If the DataSource is a DataTable, you can add an "expression" (calculated column) to the table. The expression for the new column would look like this:

```
newcolumn.Expression = "Id + ' - ' + StudentName";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your stored procedure to:

```
SELECT Id, Id + " - " StudentName as Text FROM xyz
```

And change the binding to:

```
ddlA.DataSource = // Some source
ddlA.DataTextField = "Text"
ddlA.DataValueField = "Id";     
ddlA.DataBind();     
ddlA.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select one", "0"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change the stored procedure. It's already in user at several places.

Comment: If that is the case, you need to loop through your dataset, create a new dataset and make a new column called text and assign Id + " - " + Text as its value and bind that new dataset to your combobox.

Comment: Don't transform on Data layer, do this on Presentation level

Answer (score 2):

If you have list of class to fill drop down list, this is probably best to do;

```
List<FOO> foo = new List<FOO>();

ddlFoo.DataSource = foo.Select(x => 
    new ListItem { Text = x.Text1 + " - " + x.Text2, Value = x.Id.ToString() });
ddlFoo.DataBind();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265587/databind-asp-net-list-of-listitem-to-dropdownlist-issue still need to set the DataTextField and DataValueField of your DropDownList.

Answer (score -1):

it's very simple, only you have concat fields in the query

```
SELECT Id ,Id || ' ' || StudentName ""TEXT"", 
FROM xyz
```

then you build a drop down list

```
ddlA.DataSource = // Some source
ddlA.DataTextField = "TEXT";
ddlA.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlA.DataBind();
ddlA.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select one", "0"));
```