# How to set drop down list DataTextField to display two data property fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list that is populated with data in the code behind. The `DataTextField` attribute is set with the following code:

```
ddlItems.DataTextField = "ItemName";
```

I want to display two data properties as the `DataTextField`. I tried using the following code but it didn't work. And I have researched on the net but couldn't find how to use two data properties.

```
ddlItems.DataTextField = "ItemName" + "ItemDescription";
```

What code do I need to use to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Formatting event of ddlItems which will allow you to set logic to how to convert a certain item to a string, or if it makes any sense to use in your program, have a property like RepresentingString that returns Name + Desc, and bind to that property.

Similar question with more answers and code examples:
[Format DropDownList.TextValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794746/format-dropdownlist-textvalue)

Comment: I tried using ddlItems.DataTextFormatString = string.Format("{0}, {1}", "ItemName", "ItemDescription") but it doesn't display the names and descriptions in the drop down list, it just displays "ItemName, ItemDescription".

Comment: the result of string.Format(...) itself would be just that, so that would be pointless. I suggest listening to the event where an item is being converted to text for display, allowing you to set logic into that.

Comment: I don't understand why this simple task can't be achieved elegantly in the asp code with <%$ %> syntax? Why is asp not allowing this? a bit disappointing. Or maybe there is a way and we didn't figure it out yet?

Answer (score 27):

You can use LinqToSql to make a new datasource containing a displayfield which is formatted, the way you want it to be, like:

```
var datasource = from x in products
                 select new {
                     x.Id,
                     x.Code,
                     x.Description,
                     DisplayField = String.Format("{0} ({1})", x.Code, x.Description)
                 };

comboBox.DataSource = datasource;
comboBox.DataValueField = "Id";
comboBox.DataTextField = "DisplayField";
comboBox.DataBind();
```

Comment: Superb for object typed implementations or when unable to modify the database structure.

Answer (score 4):

I have done something similar to this in two ways: either in C# or SQL.

Matteo Gaggiano below gives a good example of the C# method:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", System.Type.GetType("System.String"), "ItemName + ' - ' + ItemDescription"));

ddlItems.DataSource = dataTable;
ddlItems.DataTextField = "Title";
ddlItems.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlItems.DataBind();
```

Or it can be done in SQL:

```
SELECT ItemName + ' - ' + ItemDescription AS Title FROM yourSQLtable
```

and then using the last four lines above in the C# code.

Comment: So the new part of your answer to a C# question is that you can use SQL instead of C#?

Comment: It's been a while (I've had problems responding to messages here, which is probably my fault), but I believe that I was stating that it could be done either way.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is in .aspx file :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server" DataSourceID="YourDataSource" DataTextField='<%# Eval("Id")+" - "+Eval("Title") %>' ..... />
```

Hope useful.

Comment: Would be nice if this worked, but it just raises an error: "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name '<value of combined fields>'".

Comment: Do `<%# Eval("Id")+" - "+Eval("Title") %>` in code Behind?

Answer (score 1):

I've achieved this before but I did so using telerik radcombobox (which was capable of including an item template). The template was simply a html table and I seemingly 'concatenated' the two fields. I'm pretty sure the standard asp .net control doesn't have this functionality - but if you look around you will find a 3rd party control that will.

It is of course possible to deal with this concatenation at the business layer and define a new type (struct is probably best) with a property that contains the two fields as one string.

I'm sure there are other ways of achieving this (more efficient ways no doubt), these are just some ways I know of that may help.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from a comment on [Format DropDownList.TextValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) I learned about DataColumn.Expression ([DataColumn.Expression Property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7769334/2277954) so this may be a valid solution (In my case it was perfect):

```
DataColumn title = new DataColumn();
title.ColumnName = "Title";
title.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
title.Expression = "ItemName + ' - ' + ItemDescription";
dataTable.Columns.Add(title);

// Or in one line

dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title", System.Type.GetType("System.String"), "ItemName + ' - ' + ItemDescription"));

ddlItems.DataSource = dataTable;
ddlItems.DataTextField = "Title";
ddlItems.DataValueField = "Id";
ddlItems.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

just fill in the dropdownlist from code behind

HTML

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSample" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

VB.NET

```
        Dim Conn As SqlConnection
        Dim Comm As SqlCommand
        Dim Read As SqlDataReader

        Conn = New SqlConnection()
        Conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Read").ConnectionString

        Comm = New SqlCommand()
        Comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
        Comm.Connection = Conn
        Comm.Connection.Open()

        Read = Comm.ExecuteReader()
        ddlSample.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Seleziona", ""))
        While Read.Read()
            ddlSample.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem(Read("ID") & " - " & Read("Desc")), ReadLivelli("ID")))
        End While

        Read.Close()
        Comm.Connection.Close()
        Comm.Dispose()
        Conn.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding with entity framework code-first you could create a new field called `NameAndDescription` and set your `ddlItems.DataTextField = "NameAndDescription"`. The field can be created as follows:

```
    public String NameAndDescription
    {
        get { return this.ItemName + this.ItemDescription; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select std.Student_ID,std.Student_Name+' - '+ std.Admission_ID Student_Name 
from Student_tbl std , School_tbl sch 
where sch.School_ID = '" + School_ID + "' and std.Current_Class = '" + Class_ID + "' 
      and std.Section_ID = '" + Section_ID + "'

DL_Student.DataTextField = "Student_Name";
DL_Student.DataValueField = "Student_ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
select id, ItemName + ' - ' + ItemDescription as 'yournamecolumn' from `yourtable`
ddlItems.DataTextField = "yournamecolumn";
ddlItems.DataValueField = "id";
ddlItems.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objDT.Columns.Add("FullName", GetType(String), "time + ' ' + location")
                        objDT.AcceptChanges()
                        ddlPickUp.DataSource = objDT
                        ddlPickUp.DataTextField = "FullName"
                        ddlPickUp.DataValueField = "location"
                        ddlPickUp.DataBind()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

In C# we can bind multiple columns to a datatextfield by creating a property which is concatenation of all requisite columns like in case of Full Name

```
public string FullName
{
            get
            {
                return  RollNo + Name +  Parentage;
            }
}
```

After creating FullName property use
datatextfeild="FullName"