# Get value based on other from a dropdownlist

Tags: c#

I need to get a value from another column based on the selected item of a drop down list.

So I have a table with 3 values which are:

1. countryID
2. countryDescription
3. countryAbbreviature

and I have a dropdownlist that I fill like:

```
public void fillCountry() {
    //Fills the list with the countries in the database
    List<Country> countryList = countryService.getCountries();

    ddlCountry.DataSource = countryList;
    ddlCountry.DataTextField = "countryDesc";
    ddlCountry.DataValueField = "countryID";

    ddlCountry.DataBind();
}
```

What I need is that when the user select like Afghanistan its abbreviature is AF so I need the abbreviature stored on a variable but what I found so far on the sites are dropdowns with only 2 values always like the one I did above.

Comment: Possibly duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217481/combining-two-fields-in-a-datatextfield-is-this-possible another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837859/how-to-set-drop-down-list-datatextfield-to-display-two-data-property-fields/34205373

Comment: You mean table with 3 fields countryID, contryDescription and coutnryAbbreviature right?

Answer (score 0):

No straight way to do this, but here is a workaround.

Concatenate abreviation with Id to set as DataValueField of dropdown:

```
public void fillCountry()
{
  //Fills the list with the countries in the database
  List<Country> countryList = countryService.getCountries();

  var dataSource = countryList.Select(c=> new { DataValueField = 
  c.countryID + "~" + c.countryAbbreviature, DataTextField = c.countryDesc }).ToList();

  ddlCountry.DataSource = dataSource;
  ddlCountry.DataTextField = "DataTextField";
  ddlCountry.DataValueField = "DataValueField";

  ddlCountry.DataBind();
}
```

on server side maybe in a button click event split them by separator and get Id as well as abreviation:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string selectedValue=ddlCountry.SelectedValue;
  int id = int.Parse(selectedValue.Split('~').First());
  string abreviation=selectedValue.Split('~').Last();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is named Countries:

```
var yourSelectedId = YourDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

string yourVariable = dbContext.Countries.Where(x => x.countryID == yourSelectedId).FirstOrDefault().countryAbbreviature;
```