# C# DDL Datasource list of object. How to set DataTextField to the object's toString()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, drop-down-menu, datasource

```
MyDropDownList.DataSource = myList;
MyDropDownList.DataTextField="Name";
MyDropDownList.DataValueField="ID"; 
MyDropDownList.DataBind();
```

This is how I bind my List of objects to a dropdownlist. My Question is how do I set the DataTextField to the ToString() method of the object.

The ToString() would return ID + " " + Name

I have tried

```
MyDropDownList.DataTextField="ToString()";
```

and

```
MyDropDownList.DataTextField="ToString";
```

but, the DataTextField wants a property name, not a method name.

How, if at all, can I go about this?

Comment: there is some good info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794746/format-dropdownlist-textvalue

Comment: also DataTextField is a string check here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most correct option is to add a property to the object that you put in the list. It can be defined through an expression. e.g:

```
public class MyListItem
{
    //some code ID, Name properties and so on
    public string Description => ToString();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ID} {Name}";
    }
}
```

If this is inpossible - you can create a inhert object or wrapper-object, whose provide access to the `ToString` method of how to field.

Then you can set this property in DropDownList, like:
`MyDropDownList.DataTextField = "Description";`

**Update**

There are third option - you can create anonymous object insted object-wrapper