# RadComboBox's DataTextField Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a `RadComboBox` and I'm binding data from my `vb` code as below :-

```
    RadComboBox.DataTextField = "Value1"
    RadComboBox.DataValueField = "Value2"
    RadComboBox.DataSource = BindComboBox("Colors") -------This is my internal funcion where i call a procedure.
    RadComboBox.DataBind()
    RadComboBox.Items.Insert(0, New RadComboBoxItem("All", "All"))
```

But now I want to keep the `DataTextField` as below:-

```
    RadComboBox.DataTextField = "Value1" + "-" + "Value2"
```

Now how to accomplish this ? I have read about this in the below thread :-

```
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794746/format-dropdownlist-textvalue
```

But I could not figure out clearly how to achieve this ! Could anyone please help, ThankYou !

Comment: what's the problem when you use:  `RadComboBox.DataTextField = "Value1" & "-" & "Value2"`

Comment: @Mederic, I am getting error

Comment: Value1-Value2 is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table Table1.  (in RadComboBox.DataBind())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this in the ItemDataBound event of the RadComboBox as shown here:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/using-multiple-columns-for-datatextfield#qYWCCiG3akiNRTTuVZEa6A