# How to get Datasource() for Dropdownbox C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have table `tblDepartments` with columns `DeptID, Department, Description`. I also have dropdownbox `drpDepartments`. I want to display the contents of column `Department` on the dropdownbox. I tried using this C# code for winforms but it didn't work:

```
        drpDepartments.DataSource = dsDep.Tables["tblDepartment"];
        drpDepartments.DisplayMember = "Department";
        drpDepartments.ValueMember = "DeptID";
        drpDepartments.Text = "Choose Department";
```

How do I do it using ASP.NET C#? Thanks.

New code (still not working)

```
        sConn = new SqlConnection(sStr);
        daEmp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", sConn);
        daDep = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblDepartment", sConn);
        dsEmp = new DataSet();
        dsDep = new DataSet();

        daEmp.Fill(dsEmp, "tblEmployee");
        daDep.Fill(dsDep, "tblDepartment");

        dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dsEmp.Tables["tblEmployee"].Columns["EmployeeID"] };

        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        daDep.Fill(dt);

        drpDepartments.DataTextField = "Department";
        drpDepartments.DataValueField = "DeptID";
        drpDepartments.DataSource = dt;
        drpDepartments.DataBind();
```

Comment: drpDepartments.Databind() is missing. Also you can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105265/dropdownlist-datasource

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265587/databind-asp-net-list-of-listitem-to-dropdownlist-issue

Comment: in description you list the column names `DeptID, Department` but in code use `DepartmentID, Department`, you sure that you use right columns names?

Comment: Use `Department` instead of `Choose Department` against `DataTextField` property.

Comment: column names are right.. but still not showing up

Comment: If the column names are right, then it should work.

Comment: in which event handler is the code?

Comment: Where did you write this code? page_load, button_click, dropdown_change etc?

Comment: `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` is this what you mean?

Comment: Okey. Are you sure then dt DataTable has values in it?

Comment: Also set DataSource first before setting TextField and ValueField

Comment: can you provide full `Page_Load` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call it like this in asp.net webForms

```
        drpDepartments.DataSource = dsDep.Tables["tblDepartment"];// Set DataSource Table First
        drpDepartments.DataTextField = "Department";// Set Column Name of DataTable to set as Text Field
        drpDepartments.DataValueField = "DepartmentID";// Set Column Name of DataTable to set as Value Field
        drpDepartments.DataBind();
```

You must be using it from `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` namespace. It seems like you were using winforms namespaces.

`DataTextField` is equivalent to `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` is equivalent to `DataValueField`.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. It would effectively create an empty dropdown list since the datasource is a newly instantiated DataTable.

Comment: Should I remove `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;`? What Should I use?

Comment: The `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember ` properties are not available in web namespaces. So I assumed you were using some winforms namespaces.

Comment: You should use `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` namespace to bind the dropdown lists.

Comment: `Choose Department` and `DepartmentID` must be the name of columns in the DataTable. Check the populated DataTable in VisualStudio while debugging

Comment: What was the problem? Is that its order you set?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call DataBind()?

```
drpDepartments.DataSource = dsDep.Tables["tblDepartment"];
drpDepartments.DisplayMember = "Department";
drpDepartments.ValueMember = "DepartmentID";
drpDepartments.Text = "Choose Department";
drpDepartments.DataBind();
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `'drpDepartments' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.`

Comment: This is a separate issue from the one you asked about. You must be setting drpDepartments.SelectedValue = ??? somewhere and the value you're setting doesn't exist in the list of dropdown items (it looks for an item with the same value).

Comment: Still not showing up, but the error is gone now..Please check I have updated the codes

Answer (score 0):

```
drpDepartments.DataSource = ds1;
drpDepartments.DataTextField = "textcol";
drpDepartments.DataValueField = "valuecol";
drpDepartments.DataBind();
```

> after doing this in btn_save method
>   add this..

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", drpDepartments.SelectedValue);
```

> hope it helps.