# Listitem into a repeater in addition to a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

it is such that I must have put a drop down menu for my website where admin can choose what he just wants.

It is such that I have never many dropdownlist

I have built it like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListOverskift" runat="server">
      <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterAsk" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:ListItem><%# Eval("navn") %></asp:ListItem>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Problems are that will not accept that I have built it up this way here. which can then show use what options he / she has.

I must therefore have repeat my listeitem many times as I have many but I can not see other opportunities to build this done.

*and Why its not work for me?*

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265587/databind-asp-net-list-of-listitem-to-dropdownlist-issue. There are various ways you can achieve what you are attempting and most are described in there. You definitely can't put a repeater inside a DropDownList though!