# Connecting Two SQL Server Tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to connect the following 2 tables together:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Groups] 
(
    [Group_Id]   INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Group_Name] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Group_Desc] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Group_Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events] 
(
    [Event_Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Event_Group_Id] INT null,
    [Event_Type]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Event_Title] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Event_Id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT fk_event_group  
        FOREIGN KEY (Event_Group_Id) REFERENCES Groups (Group_Id)
);
```

First question: have I created the tables correctly?

I've been able to add to the `Events` with the following code but I haven't been able to successfully connect the PK of `Groups` as an FK in `Events`.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string findGroupOfEvent = "SELECT Group_Id FROM Groups WHERE Group_Name ='" + DropDownListEventGroup.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
        int groupId = Convert.ToInt32(findGroupOfEvent);
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Events (Event_Group_Id, Event_Type, Event_Title) VALUES (@GroupEventID, @Type, @Title)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupEventID", groupId);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownListEventType.SelectedItem.ToString());
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", TextBoxET.Text);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("ViewEvents.aspx");
        Response.Write("Registration is successful");
        conn.Close();
```

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3iVI.png)

[Adding Dropdown Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Ryz.png)

Comment: `but I haven't been able to successfully connect the PK of Groups as an FK in Events.` <= what do you mean by this? Also you should wrap your SqlConnections in `using` blocks and create a new instance every time you want to interact with the DB (do not have a central SqlConnection that you reuse!). See also [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements).

Comment: When adding a new row to the Event table, I have a Dropdown menu which contains the same text which is in [Group_Name] of [Groups]. I want to be able to get the Group_ID of the same row as the [Group_Name] selected in the DropDown Menu, and assign that value to [Event_Group_ID] in the [Events] table.

Comment: You have made no mention of anything UI, so far this question only shows Sql DDL and ADO.NET. That part code all looks fine to me with one note that you hard coded `1` in your `@GroupEventID` parameter which might or might not be your intent. If  you want help with drop down values you should show the relevant code for that.

Comment: I still have no idea what might be wrong with your code because you have not described or shown the functionality you are having problems with. I will venture a guess: when creating your drop down make sure you assign the value of each option item as the `Group_ID` of the `Groups` table and the inner html (text) as the name. During a form post you should get the ID back and you can use this as your sql parameter value. Again, no idea if that is the issue as you are forcing everyone to guess.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the UI above. The user is to select a Group from the dropdown. I would then like to add the GroupID of the selected group to the Events table as the foreign key, but it is not working

Comment: When I try to add a new group (executing the above code), I get the following error: Error: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value) at Admin.btnAddEvent_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\11342\OneDrive\Documents\4th Year\FYP\BallinoraWaterfallCommunity\Admin.aspx.cs:line 88

Comment: Again, yous should use the ID as the value of the drrop down options, not the name. You are probably trying to use int.Parse to convert a name (which is not a number) into the int. Show the relevant code for how you create the drop down and bind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `value` in your designer screen shot https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Ryz.png to 1 and then 2 etc that corresponds to the ids you used in your database table. That is why your code is failing as you cannot convert a string name to an integer. The value is the unique id (int), the name is the display text.

A much better and more maintainable option would be to dynamically generate the list items from the database values when the form/control loads. There are many already asked questions with good answers on this like [Databind ASP.NET List of ListItem to DropDownList issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265587/databind-asp-net-list-of-listitem-to-dropdownlist-issue)

Comment: That's managed to solve the problem. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @user2911539 - Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).

Answer (score 0):

And text to `GroupID` description from database while building drop down list, and you can query directly with ID in below SQL on group ID instead of group name:

```
string findGroupOfEvent = "SELECT Group_Id FROM Groups WHERE Group_ID ='" + DropDownListEventGroup.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide below details, SQL seems to fine and database also looking good:

1. Are you getting value of **DropDownListEventGroup** from UI and querying global detail table, giving you data.
2. Do you have data in groups table?

Cheers 
Sudeep

Comment: Hi, I have added a screenshot of the data in the Groups table

Comment: Can show posted data from UI to server, what is coming

Comment: When I try to submit a new event, I get the following error: Error: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value) at Admin.btnAddEvent_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\11342\OneDrive\Documents\4th Year\FYP\BallinoraWaterfallCommunity\Admin.aspx.cs:line 88

Comment: What is the value of findGroupOfEvent variable and DropDownListEventGroup.SelectedItem

Comment: The value of DropDownListEventGroup.SelectedItem.ToString() is Retired Mens Group. The value of findGroupOfEvent is SELECT Group_Id FROM Groups WHERE Group_Name ='Retired Mens Group'

Comment: Key value pair is not correct, seems like that and you are trying to convert char in int and that's where runtime failing

Comment: Just change each item in dropdownlist of

Comment: Value to GruopID from database

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Comment: Sorry man, that was not the intention. I will not post anything, sorry for inconvenience caused